# pickle.load cannot open up a (Stylegan2 network) pickle model on my local machine, but can on the cloud

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, pickle, google-colaboratory

Stylegan2 uses network pickle files to store ML models. I transfer trained one model, which I am able to open up on cloud servers. I have been generating images from this model fine with the following setup:

- Google Colab: Python 3.6.9, CUDA 10.1, tensorflow-gpu 1.15, CuDNN 7.6.5

However, I cannot open the network pickle file on my local machine, even though I've been trying to replicate that cloud setup the best I can. (I have the right GPU `hardware/drivers/etc`.)

- Local (Windows 10) Python 3.6.9, CUDA 10.1, tensorflow-gpu 1.15, CuDNN 7.6.5
- Requires a library '`dnnlib`' to be in the PYTHONPATH and for a `tf.Session()` to be initialized

I get the an assertion error about the pickle.

```
**Assertion error**: `assert state["version"] in [2,3]`
```

I find this error very odd because the network pickle works on the cloud--so it was saved properly. Additionally, my local set up can open up other network pickles(ie. ones downloaded from the internet through GET requests), making me think that I have properly set up my PYTHONPATH and initialized a `tf.Session`. These are prerequisites listed in the Stylegan repo:

> "You can import the networks in your own Python code using `pickle.load()`. For this to work, you need to include the `dnnlib` source directory in PYTHONPATH and create a default TensorFlow session by calling `dnnlib.tflib.init_tf()`"

I'm not sure why I cannot open up this pickle in one environment, but can in another. Does anyone have any suggestions as to where I might start looking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I figured it out by printing out what version was throwing the error. The version printed was '4'. I realized that this matched the pickle (HIGHEST_PROTOCOL) and that what I needed was the newest pull of the Stylegan2 repository, which included pickle format_version 4 in their allowed versions.